# How to terminate android app after each test Appium UIAutomator2

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium, uiautomatorviewer

Android application isn't closing even after using driver.close() or driver.quit() with the UiAutomator2 driver in Appium 2

it is always in an open state and needs to be closed and relaunched after completing each test case execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make this happen by setting the `appium:fullReset` capability to `true`.